# Secure TCP .NET Remoting Channel without Authentication

Tags: .net, encryption, remoting

I have a .NET 2.0 remoting application that needs to communicate between machines that may be on different domains or no domain at all. It is using the TCP channel.

Everything works fine until I enable encryption, then when connecting I get the error "The server has rejected the client credentials." I have done quite a bit of searching, and I have not been able to find a solution that works for me.

I have tried playing around with all kinds of channel settings and have not had any success.

My remoting object has its own built-in authentication, so I don't need Windows to do any kind of authentication.

**Botton line question is:**

**"Can I enable encryption on a .NET remoting TCP channel without Windows trying to authenticate the client's credentials?"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of research I came to the conclusion that this can't be done without some major custom coding using .NET remoting.

I decided to move the project to WCF which does allow the use of SSL apart from any kind of authentication. After moving to WCF everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

First, secure server and client channels, using the "secure" property/argument.Then, in the client side set username and password to an empty string.

```
IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();
properties["username"] = "";
properties["password"] = ""; 
// Set other properties here
IClientChannelSinkProvider provider = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
channel = new TcpClientChannel(properties, provider);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);
```

In this case, client connects to server as an anonymous user (NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON) and as far as i have monitored the communication between client and server, it is encrypted.

It has been so long since the question is asked and .NET Remoting is kind of deprecated but i found it useful and may help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure most folks have moved on to WCF but I wanted to put the solution that worked for me and hopefully for those that are struggling with .net remoting.  The requirement was to be able to communicate with another windows service that was running in a different domain via current the .net remoting implementation.  I knew I had to use impersonation. I tried Mehrzard's solution to no avail.  It seemed like the connection was not using the credentials that I set.  Then I found [this article](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169580&seqNum=5) and that solved my issue.  I was able to set the credentials further down the line.

```
IMyRemoteObject myObj = (IMyRemoteObject )
                Activator.GetObject(
                typeof(IMyRemoteObject ),
                CreateConnectionString());

IDictionary props =  ChannelServices.GetChannelSinkProperties(myObj );
props["username"] = "Administrator";
props["password"] = "xyz";
props["domain"] = "TestDomain";

//call the remote object
MessageBox.Show(myobj.hello());
```